# Security Issue when accessing CSS and images folder

Tags: iis-7, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I created a brand new project using the default "Web Application" template and I deployed it to a local IIS 7 folder which was set up as an application.

When I access my deployed web site, [this is what I see](http://screencast.com/t/EmKxy0JEB6gV)

It looks as though no CSS is being applied but everything looks to be in place, including the CSS files deployed to the \Styles\Site.css subfolder.

When I run it interactively, it looks like the [screen everyone has seen before](http://screencast.com/t/Aq8uJoPHf7Nz)

Can someone take a guess as to what may be causing my styles to have no style?

It appears to be a [rights issue](http://screencast.com/t/3pWVM9Vy6q). To which account must I grant access to these folders? Note that I have moved IIS' default folder, or at least tried to.

Of interest: When I compare my security settings on my default c:\inetpub folder to my current default IIS web site location, I see that the original location has granted "TrustedInstaller" full access to this folder but I do not see "TrustedInstaller" as a User, Group or Role on my machine. Can someone explain why or how this works?

IIS_IUSRS does appear to have been granted read rights to this folder.

Answer (score 1):

The permissions part isn't of interest.

IE9 has more stringent requirements for loading CSS files - tried using the Compatibility page view on it? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622939(v=VS.85).aspx

Also, doublecheck that the files are being loaded as you expect them to be (and from the correct location) - Fiddler or the F12 network capture view can help here. It could be that there's a relative pathing problem, just looking at the URLs (/content.css would work on http://localhost:port/ but not when deployed to a subfolder)

Edit: TrustedInstaller is the Windows component installer identity. It's a super-privileged user account. Unless you're seeing 401s related to folder permissions - actually, even if you are - it's not the TrustedInstaller perms you need to worry about, just the user-level, anonymous user, and app pool identity permissions.